# How to add css to chunk using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Hi i have used indexes to move particular pages using chunk  like below first image how to add css into that look better like second image or is there good way to do this kind of indexes design to move particular page using itext.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Test.pdf"));
        // step 3
        document.open();


        Chunk chunk11 = new Chunk("1");
        chunk11.setLocalGoto("1");
        chunk11.setLocalDestination("1");
        Chunk chunk12 = new Chunk("2");
        chunk12.setLocalGoto("2");
        Chunk chunk13 = new Chunk("3");
        chunk13.setLocalGoto("3");
        Chunk chunk14 = new Chunk("4");
        chunk14.setLocalGoto("4");

        document.add(new Paragraph(chunk11));
        document.add(new Paragraph(chunk12));
        document.add(new Paragraph(chunk13));
        document.add(new Paragraph(chunk14));

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

        table.addCell("Subject ");
        table.addCell(" Obtain marks ");
        result = Student_resultby_parent_daoimp.Details();

        ExaminationDTO examinationDTO = result.get(0);



        table.addCell("Kannada");
        table.addCell(Integer.toString(90));
        table.addCell("English");
        table.addCell(Integer.toString(85));

        table.addCell("Hindi");
        table.addCell(Integer.toString(95));
        table.addCell("Mathematics");
        table.addCell(Integer.toString(85));
        table.addCell("Science");
        table.addCell(Integer.toString(90));

        table.addCell("SocialStudies");
        table.addCell(Integer.toString(60));

        table.addCell("Total marks");
        table.addCell(Integer.toString(550));

        document.add(table);

        Chapter chapter = new Chapter(0);
        document.add(chapter);

        /*
         * XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new
         * FileInputStream("index.jsp"));
         */

        Chunk chunk21 = new Chunk("1");
        chunk21.setLocalGoto("1");

        Chunk chunk22 = new Chunk("2");
        chunk22.setLocalDestination("2");
        chunk22.setLocalGoto("2");
        Chunk chunk23 = new Chunk("3");
        chunk23.setLocalGoto("3");
        Chunk chunk24 = new Chunk("4");
        chunk24.setLocalGoto("4");

        document.add(new Paragraph(chunk21));
        document.add(new Paragraph(chunk22));
        document.add(new Paragraph(chunk23));
        document.add(new Paragraph(chunk24));

        table.addCell("Subject ");
        table.addCell(" Obtain marks ");
        result = Student_resultby_parent_daoimp.Details();

     examinationDTO = result.get(1);

     PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);

        table1.addCell("Subject ");
        table1.addCell(" Obtain marks ");

        table1.addCell("Kannada");
        table1.addCell(Integer.toString(10));
        table1.addCell("English");
        table1.addCell(Integer.toString(20));

        table1.addCell("Hindi");
        table1.addCell(Integer.toString(30));
        table1.addCell("Mathematics");
        table1.addCell(Integer.toString(40));
        table1.addCell("Science");
        table1.addCell(Integer.toString(50));

        table1.addCell("SocialStudies");
        table1.addCell(Integer.toString(60));

        table1.addCell("Total marks");
        table1.addCell(Integer.toString(110));

        document.add(table1);       

        document.close();
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to create a table that looks like the images marked "Expecting like this", why don't you create your `PdfPTable` in that sense? Also, why are you talking about CSS? When using `PdfPTable`, `PdfPCell`, `Chunk`, and other iText objects, there is no CSS involved. You can define the background color of a `PdfPCell` using the appropriate method, but that's not CSS. You can change the font color of a `Chunk` using the appropriate method, but that's not CSS. And so on. Please understand that your question sounds very awkward.

Comment: Essentially you have to understand that the `PdfPTable` is not an abstract data representation but a concrete visual tabular structure.

Comment: @ Bruno Lowagie ,i am a budding coder and i am new to itext and even i mentioned in my question that in which way i have to do and i i tougth to add colour,to change font size and font colour we need to use css method in itext and i do not feel its so awkward question and Please understand what others are try to say before feeling awkward.

Comment: you are right i want to create a table like   the images marked "Expecting like this" and ok i ll use PdfPTable to create